# How to redirect from category and shop pages to homepage in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to hide any category pages

- [www.thewebsite.com/product-category](http://www.thewebsite.com/product-category)

and the main shop page

- [www.thewebsite.com/shop](http://www.thewebsite.com/shop)

So I need to redirect from category links and shop page to the root of the website

- [www.thewebsite.com](http://www.thewebsite.com)

I use the code below for this, but it does more or less the opposite. any advice?

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_shop');
function redirect_to_shop() {
    // Only on product category archive pages (redirect to shop)
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        wp_redirect( wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [is_shop()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-4) and [home_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/)

So you get:

```php
function action_template_redirect() {
    /* is_product_category() - Returns true when viewing a product category archive.
     * is_shop() - Returns true when on the product archive page (shop).
     *
     * (redirect to home)
     */
    if ( is_product_category() || is_shop() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'action_template_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'wc_redirect_to_shop');
function wc_redirect_to_shop() {
    // Only on product category archive pages (redirect to root)
    if (is_product_category()) {
        wp_redirect(get_site_url());
        exit();
    }

    /**
     * Redirect shop page to root
     * Second check prevent redirect loop when front page is the as same shop page
     */
    if (is_shop() && get_site_url(null, '/') != wc_get_page_permalink('shop')) {
        wp_redirect(get_site_url());
        exit();
    }
}
```

You can use the following functions:

- [get_home_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_home_url/)
- [get_site_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/)